# Rewrite $\sin(\omega t)$ in terms of exponentials

Tags: trigonometry

Could someone please give me a pointer or two. I am trying to rewrite $\sin(\omega t)$ and it should be something similar to $\dfrac{e^{2j\omega t}-e^{-2j\omega t}}{2j}$ but I can't quite seem to get it right.

Comment: You just have some extra $2$s in the exponent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\frac{e^{i\omega t}-e^{-i\omega t}}{2i}&=\frac{\cos(\omega t)+i\sin(\omega t)-\cos(-\omega t)-i\sin(-\omega t)}{2i}\\
&=\frac{\cos(\omega t)+i\sin(\omega t)-\cos(\omega t)+i\sin(\omega t)}{2i}\\
&=\frac{2i\sin(\omega t)}{2i}\\
&=\sin(\omega t),
\end{align*}
where we used the fact that $\sin$ and $\cos$ were odd and even, respectively. So it looks like you have some extra twos in your proposed solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin{(\omega t)} = \frac{e^{i\omega t}-e^{-i\omega t}}{2i}$$where $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but an interesting alternative proof for this statement is to consider that $\sin(\omega x)$ is the unique solution to the DE $y''=-\omega^2y$ with $y'(0) = \omega$ and $y(0)=0$. However, 
$$\frac{e^{i\omega x} - e^{-i\omega x}}{2i}$$
also solves the equation. Thus by the uniqueness of the solution they must be the same.